# octokit getLabel returning TypeError: callback.bind is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror, github-api, octokit

I have this function:

```
async function paginate(method) {
  let response = await method({
    q: "repo:" + repoOrg + "/" + repoName + " is:issue",
    per_page: 100
  });
  data = response.data.items;
  var count = 0;
  while (octokit.hasNextPage(response)) {
    count++;
    console.log(`request n°${count}`);
    response = await octokit.getNextPage(response);
    data = data.concat(response.data.items);
  }
  return data;
}

paginate(octokit.search.issues)
  .then(data => {
    callback(data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Instead of running `octokit.search.issues`, I wish to run `octokit.issues.getLabel`.

I tried changing:

```
let response = await method({
  q: "repo:" + repoOrg + "/" + repoName + " is:issue",
  per_page: 100
});
```

to:

```
let response = await octokit.issues.getLabel("owner", "repo", "label_name");
```

But I got this error: `TypeError: callback.bind is not a function`.

I tried several other combinations of this buthad no luck. I also couldn't find any code examples online other than at [enter link description here](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/#api-Issues-getLabel)

Can somebody show me how this should be coded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed my filter so now include a filter on label:

```
let response = await method({
    q: "repo:" + repoOrg + "/" + repoName + " is:issue" + " label:label_name" + " state:open",
    per_page: 100
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the error `"TypeError: callback.bind is not a function"` because you pass multiple arguments here

```js
octokit.issues.getLabel("owner", "repo", "label_name")
```

Octokit expects the 2nd argument to be a callback, hence the error. What you want is this

```js
octokit.issues.getLabel({
  owner: 'owner',
  repo: 'repo',
  label_name: 'label_name'
})
```

See the documentation at http://octokit.github.io/rest.js/#api-Issues-getLabel